# Display if strtotime() is correct and valid

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a weird problem I don't understand it well

I have two time `strtotime($start)` , `strtotime($end)`

and I want to display it if the start time is less than the end time
here is the code

```
<?php 
    if(strtotime($start)< strtotime($end)) {
        the_title();
        echo date('h:i A', strtotime($start));
        echo date('h:i A', strtotime($end));
    }
?>
```

put in some results, I got

```
06:00 am
12:00 am
```

and this is not valid obviously because the clock don't spin backward :) 

So I don't know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you please show what `$start` and `$end` are at the top of the code?

Comment: but... 06:00 **is** before 12:00 ..?

Comment: Don't forget that it's comparing the DateTime, not just the time.

Comment: this seems valid in my eyes?

Comment: 06:00 am *is not before* 12:00 am,
Its a bus schedule , and this is not correct , It should be  start at (12:00 am) and end at (06:00 am)

Comment: `var_dump($start);` and `var_dump($end);` Please let us know what those values contain.